# Running Jenkins Job using only the local repository

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a Spring boot project on my local machine and I am using personal dependencies in the project. When I run  `mvn clean package` on the windows terminal it works but when I use `mvn clean package` in the Jenkins Job it does try to download dependencies in the remote repository. My question is how to force Jenkins to use my local repository without looking the remote one.

Comment: Those personal dependencies are coming from where? Other Maven projects?

Comment: @khmarbaise
personal dependencies are coming from local maven repository( /.m2/repository/ ).

Comment: That's not what I'm asking you've already wrote that... Furthermore to get things on Jenkins you should start using a repository manager (Nexus for example) ... Is the Jenkins running on a different server? Is that corporate environment?

Comment: No,the Jenkins is running on same server than where the repository is. I'm using just Maven Integration plugin.Should i use Nexus ?

Comment: Technically you could use a local directory to be used but I wouldn't recommend it...better use something like Nexus...and make a full working setup..in the end it's easier...

Answer (score 0):

You should able to use [maven option](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-embedder/cli.html) `mvn -o` or `mvn -llr`.

But that assumes ~/ is the same user Jenkins agent ia running on.

Your better bet is to use `mvn install:install-file` to [install the jars](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) locally.

You can set up your job to do a `curl`.or `wget` step to retrieve the files from "somewhere", then have your pom call a pom which installs the jars locally from workapce to repo, then does your build.

That makes your job portable and still pulls the rest of OSS jars from Central, without needed an intermediary remote.